# Compile single scala file with TypeSafe Activator

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

I have Activator installed. Which means I have a full SBT on my system. I don't want to create a brand new activator project. All I want to do is compile a single scala file as we used to do with the scalac command. How can I do this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go into the directory containing your scala file and type "sbt compile" on the command line.

To run the program, you type "sbt run"

see also
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html

Comment: Thanks, but the sbt command is not on my path. Where does activator install it to?